# Can't call openfile function

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to open a file via the menubar. However, it keeps giving me this error "TypeError: unbound method openfile() must be called with hash instance as first argument (got nothing instead)" I have never encounter this error before so I'm not sure what to do. I'm using Tkinter for my GUI.

```
 class application:
    def openfile():
        filename = askopenfilename(parent=root)
        f = open(filename)
        f.read()
        print (filename)

    def hashmd5():
        BLOCKSIZE = 65536
        hasher = hashlib.md5()
        with open(askopenfilename(), 'rb') as afile:
            buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            while len(buf) > 0:
                hasher.update(buf)
                buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
                print(hasher.hexdigest())

menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=hash.openfile)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
```

Update:
I managed to solve the errors on my codes and it's working fine but when I tried adding a login windows using labels and buttons, the windows did not appear at all.

```
import hashlib
import Tkinter as tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

class Application(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.root = root = tk.Tk()
    menubar = tk.Menu(root)
    root.title("Hashing Tool")
    root.geometry("300x150")

    filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Hash", command=self.hashmd5)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
    root.config(menu=menubar)


    self.filename = tk.StringVar()
    self.filename.set("No File Selected")
    lbl = tk.Label(root, textvariable=self.filename, anchor="w")
    lbl.pack()


    self.digest = tk.StringVar()
    lbl = tk.Label(root, textvariable=self.digest, anchor="w")
    lbl.pack()

def create_widgets(self):
        self.instruction = Label(self ,text ="enter")
        self.instruction.grid(row = 0,column = 0, columnspan = 2,sticky =W)


        self.password = Entry(self)
        self.password.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.submit_button = Button (self ,text = "submit")
        self.submit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.text = Text(self,width = 35, height = 5, wrap = WORD)

def reveal(self):
        cotent = self.password.get()

        if content == "password":
            message = "Accessed"
        else:message = "Denied"

        self.text.insert(0,0,message)

        root.mainloop()


def hashmd5(self):
    BLOCKSIZE = 65536
    hasher = hashlib.md5()
    filename = askopenfilename(parent=self.root)
    self.filename.set(filename)
    print(filename)

    with open(filename, 'rb') as afile:
        buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
        while len(buf) > 0:
            hasher.update(buf)
            buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            digest = hasher.hexdigest()
            self.digest.set(digest)
            print(digest)

Application()
```

Comment: 2nd half of https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks

Comment: 1). You should mention which GUI framework you're using, preferably with a tag. 2). `hash` is the name of a built-in function, so it's confusing to call your class `hash` (and it makes it hard to call the actual `hash()` function). FWIW, Python classes are conventionally given CamelCase names. 3). You should create an instance of your class. 4). Your `with open(...` statement isn't indented correctly.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks. I amended the above code plus the framework im using

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to write a proper answer. But the normal way to use a class in Python is to create an instance of it. Eg `app = application()`. And to make that work properly your classes methods (`openfile` and `hashmd5`) need to have a 1st arg of `self`. Take a look at the official Python docs (or Stack Overflow code) for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to organize your code. Here's one way:

```
import hashlib
import Tkinter as tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

class Application(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = root = tk.Tk()
        menubar = tk.Menu(root)

        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Hash", command=self.hashmd5)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        root.config(menu=menubar)

        #Add a Label to hold the current filename
        self.filename = tk.StringVar()
        self.filename.set("No File Selected")
        lbl = tk.Label(root, textvariable=self.filename, anchor="w")
        lbl.pack()

        #Add a Label to hold the most recent MD5 digest
        self.digest = tk.StringVar()
        lbl = tk.Label(root, textvariable=self.digest, anchor="w")
        lbl.pack()

        root.mainloop()

    def hashmd5(self):
        BLOCKSIZE = 65536
        hasher = hashlib.md5()
        filename = askopenfilename(parent=self.root)
        self.filename.set(filename)
        print(filename)

        with open(filename, 'rb') as afile:
            buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            while len(buf) > 0:
                hasher.update(buf)
                buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
                digest = hasher.hexdigest()
                self.digest.set(digest)
                print(digest)

Application()
```

If you run this on Python 3 you need to change the Tkinter import statements.

Answer (score 1):

Class methods require their first parameter to be `self`, and must be called on an instance of the class.

If you're trying to make static methods (to be called on the class itself), you should precede your methods definitions by `@staticmethod`.

e.g.

```
class hash:
    @staticmethod
    def openfile():
        # ...
```

Comment: I see. So i have to to retype it as def openfile(self)? If so, how do i return it on this particular code "filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=hash.openfile)"?

Comment: In your case, your methods wouldn't make use of the self parameter, so you're probably better off with static methods (just add `@staticmethod` on the line before the function declaration)

Comment: thanks. i amended it. But im having a new error "TypeError: openfile() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)"

Comment: If it's a static method, then you should not have a `self` argument.